# How do I highlight points by clicking on legend entries in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I am plotting a simple scatter plot with 3 groups of data, labeled A, B and C.

1. How do I write the code to allow clicking on legend entry A and highlighting points associated with A, while dimming points associated with labels B and C?
2. Is it possible to select (by click and drag, or click on multiple legend entries with ctrl key) and highlighting the associated points, while dimming points having other labels (labels not selected on the legend)?

Following the example here https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/event_handling/legend_picking.html (which uses plot instead of scatter), I have made some progress, but can't quite get the code to work the way I want it. In the example, they set the picker property for each legend entry via leg.get_lines(), and I tried a similar thing (leg.get_patches()) which gave an empty dict. I can't make further progress, hopefully someone can help. Thanks in advance.

```
import numpy as np
import tkinter as tk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

class MainApplication(tk.Frame): 
    def __init__(self, root, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, root, *args, **kwargs)
        self.root = root
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.root)
        self.frame.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.plot_button = tk.Button(self.frame, text='Plot XY', command=self.xy_plot)
        self.plot_button.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.figure = plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.figure, master=self.frame)
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=1, column=0)

        self.X = [np.random.rand(5), np.random.rand(5), np.random.rand(5)]
        self.Y = [np.random.rand(5), np.random.rand(5), np.random.rand(5)]
        self.labels = ['A','B','C']
        self.figure.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', self.onpick)

    def xy_plot(self):   
        ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)  
        self.pts = []
        for x, y, grp in zip(self.X, self.Y, self.labels):
            self.pts.append(ax.scatter(x, y, label=grp))
        leg = ax.legend(self.pts, self.labels, fontsize=12)
        leg.set_picker(5) #should be set for individual entries? If so, how?
        self.canvas.draw()

    def onpick(self, event):
        #obviously this function needs to be modified
        self.pts[0].set_alpha(0.9) 
        self.pts[1].set_alpha(0.1
        self.canvas.draw()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk() 
    MainApplication(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

All the examples that I came across involve looping over leg.get_lines() and setting the set_picker(value) for each element in leg.get_lines(). However, leg.get_lines() is empty for scatter plot. I tried looking at leg.**dict**['legendHandles'] and I see that it consists of 3 (in my case) collections.PathCollection objects. Do these objects have set_picker() methods? It seems to me that legend for a scatter is very different from legend for a plot. Can someone shed light on this?

Answer (score 1):

By analogy to the example shown in the link in my question, I looped over the legendHandles and set the set_picker(5). This allows clicking on different legend entries and allows me to get the label via event.artist.get_label(). The modification to the onpick function seems like a hack, but it does what I want. Is there a more elegant and proper way to loop over the legendHandles than what I am doing? Any suggestions to improve the "solution" is welcome.

```
def xy_plot(self):   

    ax = self.figure.add_axes([0,0,1,1])  
    self.pts = []

    for x, y, grp in zip(self.X, self.Y, self.labels):
        self.pts.append(ax.scatter(x, y, label=grp))
    self.leg = ax.legend(self.pts, self.labels)

    for obj in self.leg.__dict__['legendHandles']:
        obj.set_picker(5)

    self.canvas.draw()


def onpick(self, event):

    groups = {key: val for key, val in zip(self.labels, self.pts)}
    label = event.artist.get_label()
    for key in groups:
        if key == label:
            groups[key].set_alpha(1.0)
        else:
            groups[key].set_alpha(0.2)

    self.canvas.draw()
```

Comment: Your trick of `set_picker(5)` worked amazingly for when I needed to make the legend entry easier to click on. Now it works much easier. I do not need to carefully place my mouse on a single row of pixels in order to get it to work.